# Google Ads using FireBase + CocoaPods gives error: "duplicated symbols for architechture x86_64"

Tags: swift, firebase

```
target 'myapp' do
pod 'Firebase/Core'
#the other projects not related with Firebase
use_frameworks!
end
```

leads to this error:

> 51968 duplicated symbols for architechture x86_64

the callstack consists of compiled classes from the other frameworks.

Swift 3 , XCode 8.

Without this pod (FireBase) my project works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about `-ObjC` flag. CocoaPods added this flag into `Other linker flags` project automatically.

But this this flag my other custom projects did not build properly.
In order to fix this I did these steps.

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup I've dowloaded file under **Integrate without CocoaPods** .
2. Dragged several franeworks into file as described at **Readme.md** :
   `FirebaseAnalytics.framework`, `FirebaseCore.framework`, `FirebaseInstanceID.framework`, `GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework`, `GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework`, `GoogleToolboxForMac.framework` and for admob: `GoogleMobileAds.framework`
3. In order to prevent `-ObjC` flat that force use all libraries I've changed `Other linker flag` using `-force_load` . That is,  `-force_load GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds -force_load FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics -force_load FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore -force_load GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac -force_load GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities -force_load GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -force_load FirebaseInstanceID.framework/FirebaseInstanceID`

Do not forget to create and download **GoogleService-Info.plist** file inside console:
https://console.firebase.google.com

** EDIT **

Version 3.12 rejects `-force_load GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities`

So , now correct solution is:

`-force_load GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds -force_load FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics -force_load FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore -force_load GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac -force_load GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -force_load FirebaseInstanceID.framework/FirebaseInstanceID`